# How to retrieve value from ArrayList in android

Tags: android, json, arraylist

I am trying to retrieve values from a `json api` and displaying then in a listView. The `listView` contains 3 elements and I am also implementing `onItemClickListner()` and when an Item is clicked it will display a detailed view related to that item. I am using an `ArrayList` to store all the `json` values. Now I want to retrieve a value from that `ArrayList` so that the `OnClickListner()` will get that value and from that value the detailed view will be displayed..

I am using AsyncTask to retrieve all the json values

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... DATA) {
if(rqst_type.equals("top5"))
    {
        String url = DATA[1];
        JsonParser jParser = new JsonParser();
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONfromUrl(url);
        try
        {
            JSONArray top5 = json.getJSONArray(TAG_TOP5);
            public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> top5List = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            top5List.clear();
            for(int i=0; i<top5.length(); i++)
            {
                Log.v(TAG_LOG, "Value of i: "+String.valueOf(i));
                JSONObject t = top5.getJSONObject(i);
                course_id = t.getString(TAG_CRSID);
                created_date = t.getString(TAG_CRTDATE);
                golfcourse_name = t.getString(TAG_GLFCRSNAME);
                facilities = t.getString(TAG_FCLTY);
                holes = t.getString(TAG_HOLES);

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put(TAG_CRSID, course_id);
                map.put(TAG_CRTDATE, created_date);
                map.put(TAG_GLFCRSNAME, golfcourse_name);
                map.put(TAG_FCLTY, facilities);
                map.put(TAG_HOLES, holes);

                top5List.add(map);
                Log.v(LoadingScreen.TAG_LOG, "top5List: "+String.valueOf(top5List));
            }
        }
        catch(JSONException e)
        {
            Log.v(TAG_LOG, String.valueOf(e));
        }
}

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    if(rqst_type.equals("top5"))
    {
        Intent in = new Intent(context, MyTop5.class);
        in.putExtra(TAG_CRSID, course_id);
        in.putExtra(TAG_CRTDATE, created_date);
        in.putExtra(TAG_GLFCRSNAME, golfcourse_name);
        in.putExtra(TAG_FCLTY, facilities);
        in.putExtra(TAG_HOLES, holes);
        Log.v(TAG_LOG, "Valuse to MyTop5: "+course_id+" "+created_date+" "+golfcourse_name+" "+
                facilities+" "+holes);
        context.startActivity(in);
    }
```

This is the file to where I am displaying the list and the `onItenClickListner()`..

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_top5);

    Intent in = getIntent();
    golfcourse_name = in.getStringExtra(TAG_GLFCRSNAME);
    course_id = in.getStringExtra(TAG_CRSID);
    created_date = in.getStringExtra(TAG_CRTDATE);
    facilities = in.getStringExtra(TAG_FCLTY);
    holes = in.getStringExtra(TAG_HOLES);
    Log.v(LoadingScreen.TAG_LOG, "course id: "+String.valueOf(course_id));
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, LoadingScreen.top5List, R.layout.top5_list,
            new String[] { TAG_GLFCRSNAME, TAG_CRSID, TAG_CRTDATE, TAG_FCLTY, TAG_HOLES },
            new int[] { R.id.top_golfname, R.id.top_courseid, R.id.top_createdate, R.id.top_fclty, R.id.top_holes });

    setListAdapter(adapter);
    Log.v(LoadingScreen.TAG_LOG, "course id: "+String.valueOf(course_id));
    ListView lv = getListView();

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String url = "http://mygogolfteetime.com/iphone/viewdeal/127";
            new LoadingScreen(MyTop5.this).execute("view_detail", url);
        }
    });
}
```

In the given URL I want to change the 127 to the value which is stored in the `top5List`.

```
String url = "http://mygogolfteetime.com/iphone/viewdeal/127";
```

The value I am trying to find in the `top5List` is the value of "`course_id`"

Thanks in advance..

Comment: your code is confusing. you are starting new activity with already parsed values and then again you are parsing with another link in that activity onclick listener. This is totally confusing. Give clear code, then you may get perfect answer soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
top5List.get(your position).get(your Key);
```

With this code you can find the value on which you want to change.